# Odd output for console.log between node.js and chrome browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm playing with node's `crypt()` and just wanted visual confirmation that the Diffie-Hillman shared secret between node ('Alice') and the Chrome client ('Bob') was matching up.  I send the public keys over socket.io to each other just fine, and they output correctly with base64 encoding in their respective console outputs, but when I output the shared secret, node's console displays correctly, but Chrome's console gives me an array of numbers.  Any thoughts?

node's code:

```
var Alice = crypto.getDiffieHellman(group);
Alice.generateKeys('base64');

console.log("receiving Bob's public key from browser");
var BobsPublicKey = message.data;
console.log(BobsPublicKey);

console.log("sending Alice's public key to browser");
var AlicesPublicKey = Alice.getPublicKey('base64');
console.log(AlicesPublicKey);
client.emit('message', AlicesPublicKey);

// compute shared secret
var AlicesSharedSecret = Alice.computeSecret(BobsPublicKey, 'base64', 'base64');
console.log("Alice's shared secret:");
console.log(AlicesSharedSecret);
```

node's console output (shortened for brevity):

```
receiving Bob's public key from browser
pyfizI3ALSz6EWnsf4pd3Pc7IVbJyKcLcmbbX1L9jpmZeM...
sending Alice's public key to browser
cVq2kVHzkSbU/aSwMXmm6CaohiLASnSabuUgp6bsyNMXia...
Alice's shared secret:
dJqcCugMDw2qCNVZ4ZftLT/rPrOZwfW7PfHJLAh4bGyIyP...
```

client-side code:

```
Bob = crypto.getDiffieHellman(group);
Bob.generateKeys('base64');

console.log("sending bob's public key from login.vue");
var BobsPublicKey = Bob.getPublicKey('base64');
console.log(BobsPublicKey);
this.serverRequest( "client", "passKey", BobsPublicKey);

console.log("receiving Alice's public key from node");
var AlicesPublicKey = message.data;
console.log(AlicesPublicKey);

// computer shared secret
var BobsSharedSecret = Bob.computeSecret(AlicesPublicKey, 'base64', 'base64');
console.log("Bob's shared Secret: ");
console.log(BobsSharedSecret);
```

client-side console output:

```
sending bob's public key from login.vue 
pyfizI3ALSz6EWnsf4pd3Pc7IVbJyKcLcmbbX1L9jpmZeMl0dI9w...
receiving Alice's public key from node
cVq2kVHzkSbU/aSwMXmm6CaohiLASnSabuUgp6bsyNMXiaom7V...
Bob's shared Secret: 
[245, 129, 185, 24, 198, 67, 220, 163, 212, 16, 152, 228, 241, 170, 91, 23, 140, 72, 245, 135, 97, 228, 32, 111, 40, 35, 155, 29, 237, 67, 212, 162, 142, 149, 29, 196, 161, 198, 123, 175, 225...
```

Comment: First of all StackOverflow isn't a fix-my-code website. It's purpose is to answer certain errors or look for tips how to deal with certain issues. Secondly, your subject doesn't describe your real problem stated in the post. PS: debuging is the key to victory. Strip your code to few functions and use browser console to debug

Comment: First off, I've never asked anyone to "fix my code" in all the time I've been on SO - something you would have known if you bothered to view my profile.  I asked only for thoughts in *this* question, and in the past I have asked for any hints or suggestions to point me in the right direction.  In this particular case, I think it is pretty clear I am asking for commentary that might explain the console behavior

Secondly, the subject lightly points out an odd behavior that I am getting and I'm not sure how to interpret what is going on, as it is clearly not what is expected.

Comment: Third, the body of the post contains a supporting definition and code / output samples.  While the question might be sparse, it is as concise and to the point as I thought was needed, with the intention that it becomes clearer by reading the full post.

Fourth, had you bothered to pay attention to the content of the post, I *am* obviously using the browser console to debug - that is how I discovered the unexpected behavior in the first place when using identical code on both client and node server!

Comment: If you don't have anything constructive to add, please refrain from applying bad interpretations to my questions.

Comment: Still "odd result" gives no clue about the problem and code you posted is not sufficient to reproduce your issue. Giving minuses to my questions won't help you get any result.

Comment: i never minused your questions, Luke. I don't even know if you've made any questions.  And how much more clearer can I make "using the same code on client and node server results in different output on their respective console outputs.  any thoughts as to why?" (which is the post in a nutshell)

Comment: @Luke thedigitalmouse isn't the downvoter. I contacted a moderator to handle that. This will be solved, don't worry (votes reverted, downvoter admonished).

Comment: -2 reputation on 3 different posts in different programming languages just after your response. But nevermind that. How about the subject like: crypto.computeSecret returns array of numbers instead of string. Also please make a jsfiddle or something similar to reproduce your problem

Comment: why would it produce an array when the parameters invoke base64 encoding (as shown in the snippets) for both input and output? and that it outputs correctly on node's console.log() but appears like a buffer on Chrome's console.log().  of course as I say that, you might not know how node's crypto library works.   there might be a small chance that console on node behaves differently than console on Chrome regarding that one crypto function. :P just appears confusing as the two earlier console.log() outputs behave as expected (base 64 output) on both sides.

Comment: @thedigitalmouse when you give us a full (not) working code for browser to reproduce - we will be able to investigate why does it happens and test our solutions how to make it work correctly. You can hardcode all the strings only to preproduce that crypto output issue. To serve you an answer a test environment will be needed anyway.

Comment: i don't think a jsfiddle will be of much help in this case, as you would have to set up a node.js session to test boths sides.  but it is something I probably should consider, thanks.

Comment: As you said - node.js results in correct answer so I assume that there is no need to care about that. Issue is on browser's side

Comment: the other problem will be to include the crypto node module on the client side in jsfiddle.  trivial when using vue.js and a browserify/webpack setup.  i don't think jsfiddle supports that. looking into it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133356/discussion-between-luke-and-the-digitalmouse).

Comment: would love to, but will have to wait for another time, as i am needed elsewhere.  thanks for your efforts thus far.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same issue.  Sure would be nice if someone had answered you instead of harassing you.

Comment: @ChrisStanley I ended up 'rolling my own' version of the Diffe-Hellman in Javascript using this article: http://www.soa-world.de/echelon/2010/09/diffie-hellman-key-exchange-in-javascript.html and using the BigInt Javascript library by Leemon Baird.  

Once a socket.io connection is established between browser and node server, they generate their own secret keys randomly at the start of each session, so the shared key is different each time.  once converted to base64, the keys show 'normally' on both sides.  With HTTPS and some AES during login data exchange, we're reasonably secure.

Comment: I see.  I actually had figured out why it was outputting an array. It's actually a buffer stream. Even telling it to output as hex doesn't output as hex. Not sure why, but adding `.toString('hex')` created the appropriate output. Glad you found a way too though!

Comment: interestingly, I originally did the `.toString('hex')` but never got the same result as you.  keeping it base64 seemed to work for me best.